# Drawing point in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I try to draw some points by coding. But the 1px width point seems has feature at the edge.
Even I try to draw some position ten times.

This is my code:

```
private function createPoint(radio:Number, rep:int):Shape{
        var s:Shape = new Shape();

        var i:int = rep;
        while( i-- > 0 ){
              s.graphics.beginFill(0, 1);
              s.graphics.drawRect(0,0, radio, radio);
              s.graphics.endFill();
  }

  return s;
```

}

Comment: Are you adding (addChild) the Shape to the displayList? And is the background your are drawing on different than your fill colour?

Comment: What value are you using as `radio`?

Answer (score 2):

```
    private function drawPoint():void
    {
         this.addChild( createPoint(10) );
    }

    // param must be >= 1
    private function createPoint(radio:uint):Shape
    {
         var s:Shape = new Shape();
         s.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00, 1);
         s.graphics.drawRect(0,0, radio, radio);
         s.graphics.endFill();

         return s;
     }
```

Will certainly work. You may not of been adding the returned shape into the display list.